# ArcGIS reloadData runs very slow on iOS

Tags: ios, performance, sdk, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-ios

So I have some points on a map. I've written code to allow the user to drag a point around the screen which more or less looks like this.

```
- (void) mapView:(AGSMapView *) mapView didMoveTapAndHoldAtPoint:(CGPoint)screen mapPoint:(AGSPoint *)mappoint graphics:(NSDictionary *) graphics    {
    [self.polyLine updatePoint:mappoint onPath:0 atIndex:self.indexOfPointBeingMoved];
    [layerThatThePolyLineIsIn dataChanged];
}
```

However, this implementation seems to be amazingly laggy. Is it just me or the esri's ArcGIS SDK very bogged down and inefficient?

Comment: I am facing same issue..

Comment: I ended up switching to Route-me.

Comment: This question is about software the asker says he/she is no longer using so any necessary follow up to get it answered is unlikely.